# Bash Function help, Empty output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write this function that searches for vowels in string

```
x="A\|E\|I\|O\|U\|a\|e\|i\|o\|u"


string () {
        if echo $1 | grep -q $x
        then
        echo $1 | tr -d $x
        fi
}

string
```

When i run it, it returns empty string

I have tried to recreate this with out function and it worked

```
x="A\|E\|I\|O\|U\|a\|e\|i\|o\|u"


if echo $1 | grep -q $x
then
echo $1  | tr -d $x
fi
```

No function:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01:~# bash test2.sh "This website is for losers LOL!"
Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!
```

With function:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01:~# bash test.sh "This website is for losers LOL!"
root@ubuntu-2gb-fra1-01:~#
```

Can anyone explain to me what's the reason?
Thanks

Comment: Inside the function, `$1` refers to the first argument passed *to the function* (not to the script), and you didn't pass any arguments to the function. Also, you should double-quote all variable references. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this.

Comment: Btw, `$x` is a regular expression, so passing it to `tr` doesn't make much sense -- `tr` expects just a list of characters. As it is, it'll remove all vowels *and also the `|` character*, because those are the characters in the string. (It doesn't remove backslash, because `tr` treats that as an escape rather than a literal character.)

Answer (score 1):

You run your function `string` without parameters. Hence inside `string` $1 is always empty and the condition is never met.

You can for instance call it as

```
string "$1"
```

to forward the current first argument to your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following line at the beginning of your code:

```
i=$1
```

and change the reference of variable in function from $1 to $i.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep` or `tr` for this.

```sh
string () {
    case $1 in
     *[AEIOUaeiou]*)
        echo "${1//[AEIOUaeiou]/}";;
     *) echo "$1";;
    esac
}
```

But of course, the substitution does nothing if the string doesn't contain any of those characters, so all of this can be reduced to

```sh
string () {
    echo "${1//[AEIOUaeiou]/}"
}
```

The `case` statement is portable all the way back to the original Bourne shell, but the `${variable//pattern/replacement}` syntax is specific to Bash.

Call it like `string "$1"` to run it on the script's first command-line argument.